# Create user-friendly date in PHP

Tags: php, date-formatting

System returns me that date `20110408`.

Is it possible to covert it to `8 April 2011`? I'm using PHP5. Can't figure out how to do that with DateTime class.

Comment: You can't figure out how to work with DateTime?  What have you tried?  Show some code, please.  And for the sake of all that is good and holy, *don't* fall back to just using the `date` function.  In DateTime, it's called `format`.

Comment: Before ask a Question please try to find out the basic answers using google. Your this question is a very basic question about PHP date-formating.

Comment: @Charles Oh the irony... every answer uses `date()`.

Comment: @Phoenix, stop depressing me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function <--

```
$original_date = '20110408';
date('d F Y', strtotime($original_date));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
date("j F Y", strtotime('20110408'));
```

Answer (score 1):

try these

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br />";
echo date("F j, Y")."<br />";
echo date("j F Y")."<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use:

```
function formatDate($date) {
    // 20110408 -> 8 April 2011
    $months = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
    $year = substr($date, 0, 4);
    $month = $months[intval(substr($date, 4, 2))-1];
    $day = (int)substr($date, -2);
    return sprintf("%d %s %d", $day, $month, $year);
}
```

I hope that's not too easy!